# Laravel Generator Can't be install on php 5.3 & 5.4

Tags: php, laravel, wamp, generator

I tried to install https://github.com/JeffreyWay/Laravel-4-Generators
on my local machine using wamp
on php 5.3.13 but it asked me for minimum requirement 5.4

I installed 5.4 package from wampserver but still can't install it

the install command
composer require way/generator

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are in windows as I guess you are

Open Control Panel -> system -> Advanced tab -> Enviroment Variables
Choose path from down area 
Click edit
Change the path for php from C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.3.13 to C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.4.0 or whatever php 5.4.x version that you have

Please note if you have wamp installed in some other directory rather than the default one please check folder in explorer before you edit it

and I think it should be fine with you now